# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Soy nuevo en esto de android estudio e intento hacer un conversor de temperaturas el problema es que por mas que lo intento sigo consiguiendo este error se supone que todo el programa debo hacerlo orientado a objetos

> 01-29 07:44:26.967 12711-12711/com.example.brolix.ctemperatura E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                    Process: com.example.brolix.ctemperatura, PID: 12711
>                                                                                    java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
>                                                                                        at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:267)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
>                                                                                        at com.example.brolix.ctemperatura.MainActivity$3.onEditorAction(MainActivity.java:66)
>                                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.onEditorAction(TextView.java:4794)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.performEditorAction(EditableInputConnection.java:139)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:304)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)

Este es mi main activity tengo entendido que mi problema es la conversión de datos de mi metodo (double)

```
 EditText C, F, K;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    C = findViewById(R.id.celciusnumero);
    F = findViewById(R.id.farennumero);
    K = findViewById(R.id.kelvinumero);

    final celcius c = new celcius();
    c.setLetra('C');
    final fahrenheit f = new fahrenheit();
    f.setLetra('F');
    final kelvin k = new kelvin();
    k.setLetra('K');

    try {
        C.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                k.setNumero(Double.parseDouble(K.getText().toString()));
                f.setNumero(Double.parseDouble(F.getText().toString()));
                c.conversion(f);

                F.setText(f.getNumero().toString());

                c.conversion(k);

                K.setText(k.getNumero().toString());
                return false;
            }
        });
        F.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                k.setNumero(Double.parseDouble(K.getText().toString()));
                c.setNumero(Double.parseDouble(C.getText().toString()));

                f.conversion(c);

                C.setText(c.getNumero().toString());

                f.conversion(k);

                K.setText(k.getNumero().toString());

                return false;
            }
        });
        K.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                f.setNumero(Double.parseDouble(F.getText().toString()));
                c.setNumero(Double.parseDouble(C.getText().toString()));

                k.conversion(c);

                C.setText(c.getNumero().toString());

                k.conversion(f);

                F.setText(f.getNumero().toString());

                return false;
            }
        });
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor copia el error que te sale aca, las imagenes son muy dificiles de ver...

Comment: Listo lo edite gracias por mencionarlo

Comment: Lo que te esta diciendo el error es que uno de los numeros no es en realidad un numero. Muy probablemente no estes encontrando el objeto en la vista. podes hacer un debug y chequearlo?

Comment: Que exactamente estas escribiendo en los TextView `R.id.farennumero` y `R.id.kelvinumero`?

Comment: Pues ese es el debug es lo que me arroja y la app funciona hasta el momento en que introduzco números en los Textedit en ese momento es cuando la app deja de funcionar y en la pantalla debug sale ese texto los text edit estan bloqueados a puros signedNumber

Comment: El mensaje te dice que estás pasando "" (la cadena vacía) a una función que lo parsea como `Double`. El stacktrace te dice exactamente en qué línea llamas a esa función (busca el nombre de tu clase en el stacktrace, allí estará el número de línea) y allí es donde le pasas el valor incorrecto.

Comment: Ninguno de tus listeners hacen una validación antes de intentar algo como esto: `k.setNumero(Double.parseDouble(K.getText().toString()));` o esto : `f.setNumero(Double.parseDouble(F.getText().toString()));`. Parece que en efecto alguno de los `TextView` no tiene más que una cadena vacía, la cual tú intentas convertir a `Double`. Para evitarlo puedes evaluar 1º o bien hacerlo así:  `k.setNumero(new Double(K.getText().toString()));` Deberías cambiar todos los demás...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El datos que estas transformando es "" por lo tanto el programa va a  fallar, es muy importante que al obtener datos directamente de la pantalla hagas validaciones.

Por ejemplo:

1) Valida si el dato es null o se devuelve vacio.
  
 `if(K.getText().toString().isEmpty){ //<-- Esto devuelve un booleano
  // Si esta vacío
   }`
 
2) Comprueba que el dato es un double 
   
  - Puedes usar el clásico try catch

```
 try {
    //Aqui la validacion
}
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // Si entra aqui significa que el dato no es un número.
}
```

3)Tambien una expreción regular:
    
     `String decimalPattern = "([0-9]*)\\.([0-9]*)";

String number="20.00";

boolean match = Pattern.matches(decimalPattern, number);
System.out.println(match); //if true then decimal else not`

Answer (score 2):

El error se describe aquí:

> NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "" at
>   java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63) at
>   java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:267) at
>   java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301) at

estas tratando de convertir a `double` un `String` vacio, lo cual es incorrecto.

Te aconsejo realices la validación para determinar si el valor es un `String` vació ( en este caso puedes asignar como default un valor de 0) o contiene un valor numérico, si contiene un valor numérico realiza la conversión

En Android puedes usar el método `isEmpty()` de la clase `TextUtils` para determinar si el `String` es es nulo o de longitud cero:

```
String valorK = K.getText().toString()
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(valorK)) {
    valorK = "0"; //Asigna valor default
}    
k.setNumero(Double.parseDouble(valorK));

String valorF = F.getText().toString()
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(valorF)) {
    valorF = "0"; //Asigna valor default
}
f.setNumero(Double.parseDouble(valorF));
```

---

Con lo anterior se resuelve el caso en que el `String` es vació, pero **la mejor opción sería validar el caso en el cual el valor no es numérico**, para esto puedes usar este método:

```
public static boolean esNumerico(String number){
    boolean result = false;
    try{
        if(number != null){
            Double.parseDouble(number);
            result = true;
        }
    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
        nfe.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

y aplicarlo de esta forma, estableciendo en caso de no ser numerico un valor default de 0:

```
  k.setNumero(Double.parseDouble(esNumerico(K.getText().toString())?K.getText().toString():"0"));
  f.setNumero(Double.parseDouble(esNumerico(F.getText().toString())?F.getText().toString():"0"));
```

---

Otra variación del método `esNumeric()` el cual retorna un valor default (0) en caso de no ser numérico :

```
public static double esNumerico(String number){
    double result = 0;
    try{
        if(number != null){
            result = Double.parseDouble(number);
        }
    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
        nfe.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Reduciría el código y se aplicaría de esta forma:

```
 k.setNumero(esNumerico(K.getText().toString()));
 f.setNumero(esNumerico(F.getText().toString()));
```

Comment: Creo que es mejor respuesta que la aceptada. Aunque cambiaría el `isNumeric`, haciendo que devuelva un `0` en vez de `false`, y así me ahorro los operadores ternarios en el uso de `isNumeric`.