# Me aparece el siguiente error en android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

**Mensaje de error en Logcat**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.admin.tallerandroid.fede.tallerandroid, PID: 1833
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.admin.tallerandroid.fede.tallerandroid/com.example.admin.tallerandroid.fede.tallerandroid.TallerAndroid}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
               Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
                  at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
                  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
                  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
                  at com.example.admin.tallerandroid.fede.tallerandroid.TallerAndroid.onCreate(TallerAndroid.java:24)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**El siguiente código esta resumido, de este punto en adelante da el mismo error**

```
package com.example.admin.tallerandroid.fede.tallerandroid;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TallerAndroid extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btn;
    TextView txt;
    EditText v1;
    TextView res;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_taller_android);

        this.btn=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        this.txt=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.textView) ;
        this.v1=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.val1) ;

        final String vv1 = v1.getText().toString();
        final int a = Integer.parseInt(vv1);
    }
}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TallerAndroid">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
        android:textSize="40px"
        android:text="@string/sumar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/btn1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/val1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="109dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/val2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="161dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/resultado"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="152dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="139dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Federico M, te sugiero buscar en el sitio el error en el sitio y encontrarás dos preguntas que responde a lo mismo : https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=NumberFormatException%3A+Invalid+int%3A+%22%22+ en caso de no encontrar información puedes preguntar en el sitio, saludos!

Comment: Posible duplicado de [java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/134533/java-lang-numberformatexception-invalid-double)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estás quriendo parsear como entero un string vacío.
La secuencia en tu actividad es: 
- se crea la actividad
- se guarda el contenido de v1 en vv1. Aquí v1 está vacío porque recién se crea la actividad.
- se intenta convertir el contenido de vv1 (aún vacío por lo anterior) en entero. Eso lanza la excepción.

Fijate que en el log te dice `Invalid int: ""`  esa doble comilla indica que estas queriendo convertir un string vacío.

Tendrías que asegurarte que vv1 no esté vacío y solo contenga números antes de parsearlo

Answer (score -1):

el error se encuentra en las siguientes lineas:

`final String vv1 = v1.getText().toString();
final int a = Integer.parseInt(vv1);`

El problema es que estas tratando de convertir un String vació a entero, lo cual es incorrecto.

en el LogCat te explica el error:
`java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""`

Las doble comillas significa vació, lo que puedes hacer para solucionar el error es lo siguiente:

`int a ;
if (vv1.isEmpty()) {
    a = 0;
}else{
    a = Integer.parseInt(vv1);
}`

De esta manera evitas el error al inicializar tu variable a.

Comment: Serna!, ayúdanos a indicar a los usuarios sobre preguntas que hayan sido respondidas para evitar preguntas repetir preguntas, saludos!

Comment: @Jorgesys tienes razón disculpa soy nuevo en el sitio y había olvidado ese detalle. saludos

Comment: Un consejo mas @Serna, cuando pongas código, ponle un tab adelante asi te lo marca como tal, o 2 espacios

Comment: @ManucoBianco Muchas gracias por el consejo, saludos.